# Draw a ball as object in canvas

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, canvas

I have this declared the next square, that's easy, but now I want to do the same for a circle...

How I can do it? Thank You.

```
//Create Var
var squa = new Square(320, 380, 50, 50);

//Define the square
function Square(x, y, width, height) {
    "use strict";
    this.x = (x === null) ? 0 : x;
    this.y = (y === null) ? 0 : y;
    this.width = (width === null) ? 0 : width;
    this.height = (height === null) ? this.width : height;
}

//Draw the square as object
squa.fill(ctx);
```

Comment: Why not just make a `function  Circle(x, y, r){ ... }`? And use `arc()`. You can go about it in the same way.

Comment: Becouse Im worng and using Circle(x,y,w,h,r){...}, but now with (x, y, r) works perfect, thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go about this in the same about you did for the `Square`. The only real difference is using the `arc(x, y, r, startAngle, endAngle)` method. With it to draw a circle you define the `startAngle` and `endAngle` to be 0 and 2pi. Like so: `arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2)`. For drawing a circle you first need to call `ctx.beginPath();` to state that you are going to draw some path or arc. For example this draws a circle at `(100,100)` with a radius of 10:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.fill(); // fill() is to fill in the circle, stroke() is for a empty circle.
```

So using the same style of coding that you used above, here is how you can make a `Circle`. As you can see it's done in practically the same way. Here is a Snippet below:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

//Create Var
var circ = new Circle(100, 100, 20);

//Define the circle
function Circle(x, y, r) {
    "use strict";
    this.x = (x === null) ? 0 : x;
    this.y = (y === null) ? 0 : y;
    this.r = (r === null) ? 0 : r;
    
    this.fill = function(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

//Draw the circle as object
circ.fill(ctx);
```

```css
canvas{ border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200 id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: +1 for good code reuse. You might want to pull .fill out into Circle.prototype for even better code reuse.

Comment: @markE Your right, I'm unsure how the OP defined their `fill` function. So I defined it like so in case the user did not know about prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple circle can be created by using the arc(x, y, radius, start-position-usually-zero, end-position-usually-three-sixty-degree).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.arc(50, 50, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
context.fillStyle = 'FFF000';
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

For drawing a ball as an object just wrap this up in a function with parameters - x-axis, y-axis, radius, and color-of-the-ball

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//invoking the object
var cir = new circle(30, 30, 15, '#000FFF');

function circle(x, y, radius, color){
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
}
```

```css
canvas{
  background-color: #fff000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```